# Facebook comments plugin not showing up in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, facebook

I created a Facebook app ID as directed over at https://developers.facebook.com. Then I used that ID to generate the comments social plugin code for my blog which looks like this:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.7&appId=1789276651307619";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>

<div class="fb-comments" data-href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" data-width="600" data-numposts="5"></div>
```

The only modification I made to the generated code is the little PHP that generates the post's URL dynamically (`<?php the_permalink(); ?>`) in the last line. I added this exact snippet in my theme's `single.php` file.

However, when the page loads, all I see where the FB comments plugin should be is a big blank space. Just to be sure, I tried opening the page in a completely different browser and had similar results. I also tried doing this through plugins to no avail. For what it's worth, the plugins I tried were the ones from Alex Moss and Kevin Partner. The blog in question is at **peppyburro.com/blog**. I also have the FB app ID duly updated in my header:

```
<meta property='fb:app_id' content='1789276651307619' />
```

I hope this isn't a duplicate question since I have already browsed through all related questions thoroughly – not only on SO but elsewhere – and couldn't find a solution to any question that describes the exact same problem.

Also, I have a similar FB comments plugin working perfectly fine on another (older, to be phased out) blog at the same site: **peppyburro.com/blogs**.

Comment: would you like to show FB comment with the help of this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/facebook-comments-master/ you can also use the shortcode of this plugin

Comment: Not unless absolutely necessary.